# Why is VBScript slow when it comes to unzipping files?

Tags: zip, javascript, 7-zip, vbscript, unzip

I know that there are of course going to be some struggles. But I'd love to know what specifically makes it so much slower, compared to a JavaScript equivalent, or just using 7-Zip.

Comment: I don't know the exact answer, but it's likely to do with CPU threads. 7Zip will use all cores to share the workload, unless expressely told otherwise.

Comment: What exactly are you _doing_ in VBScript? Are you loading a native-code module to do the main job, or are you implementing all the decompression algorithms in VBScript directly? Likewise, does the JS version load a native module?

Comment: Also, are you comparing against the Windows JScript runtime, or against something more modern such as the Node JavaScript runtime?

Comment: @grawity most likely it is the native-code for VBScript. As for the JS, it's definitely not Node JS, though I'm not too sure. The zipping JS I was talking about comes from [here](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/zipjs.bat)

Also, for what I've been using when it comes to VBScript is [here](https://github.com/TheAlienDrew/Custom-Scripts-and-Commands/blob/master/Windows/zip%20%26%20unzip%20(CMD%20only)/zip_unzip.bat)